# Reset autoincrement to fill empty gaps

Tags: mysql

I'm currently building a simple userdatabase where I'm using AUTO INCREMENT to get a unique user id. When I delete a single user there will be a gap in the user id. I'm curious if it's possible to make auto increment fill in these empty gaps instead of using the next highest number:

user id
1000
1001
1002
1004

Right now the next user id I insert into the table will be 1005, but I would like it to be 1003 instead. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible. Don't do it. `auto_increment` has a purpose, and it's not to give you pretty sequential numbers, it's to uniquely identify a record. If you need some sort of sequential numbering, create a trigger and ensure you have consistency yourself. There are many reasons and many implications of tampering with `auto_increment`. TL;DR: don't do it and forget about it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Even though user 1003 has been deleted, if you reuse that id it could lead to confusion over whether records refer to the new 1003 or the deleted one.

Comment: Really just curious. How do you handle the fact that you some day will reach the maximum value? Or du just set like LONG INT and hope for the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No with autoincrement this is not possible. You will need to manually do it some extra coding.
Normally, if you keep the maxvalue high enough, skipped record wouldn't be much of a problem.