# How to generate a auto generated and auto corrected column in sql table using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

I am trying to make a column using Auto increment. I'm using this column as a serial no. column for the table but the problem is when a record is deleted from the table then the auto increment is taking the new record with the next number and that serial no. is forever gone which I don't want I want that if a record is deleted than it should take that no in next coming record,So please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good idea to do that.

Possible duplicate:

[How to fill in the "holes" in auto-incremenet fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841104/how-to-fill-in-the-holes-in-auto-incremenet-fields)

[Using unused primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967588/using-unused-primary-keys/12967713#12967713)

[Reset autoincrement to fill empty gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897187/reset-autoincrement-to-fill-empty-gaps)